# NetBeans line wrap for generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, netbeans

Does anyone know how to get line-wrapping to work with generic type parameters in NetBeans? For example if I have:

```
TuttiFruttiClass<A, Wop, Bop, Aloo, Mop, Alomp, Bom, Boom> foo;
                                           ^ suppose 80 column mark here
```

I'd like to set line-wrapping for after `Mop,`. Currently it seems that even if I manually do this, auto-format will put everything back on one line.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2

Comment: I warn you, though I don't know how to turn on line wrapping in Netbeans, having your code linewrap will lead to difficulties in reading the code. It is better that if you must do a form of a "line wrap" that you manually break the line where you need to.

Comment: @blahfunk Fair, but unfortunately I'm not in a position to decide that. This code base conforms to the google java style guide, which requires line-wrapping in this case.

Comment: can you just manually do that break yourself? The line is on the screen in netbeans...

Comment: @blahfunk I can, but the next time I use the auto-format tool in NetBeans (for instance, to auto format block comments) it will revert it back to all on one line.

Comment: I wish I could be of more help, but linewrapping is not an issue for me in netbeans. I just format it directly on the screen always if I need a line to wrap.